# Compare a long single-line XML between versions in TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I've got a WSDL service definition checked into our repository. I've noticed that it has changed between versions, and I would like to see what exactly has been changed.

Unfortunately, said WSDL file is a singe-line XML file, albeit a pretty long one. TFS compare shows the entire line as changed, which isn't really helpful.

How can I compare changes between versions for a long single-line XML file in TFS?

PS. Obviously I could copy both versions, format them, and use an external comparing tool. What I'd like to know if there's a way to do this comparison using tools provided by VS / TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an external tool as Visual Studio can compare any file, even local files located on the local file system:

[image]

But you still need to do some formatting (a basic search ">" and replace ">\n" would do though) in order to locate the lines which have changed.

Comment: But I take it there's no way to do this in a fast and efficient manner? I still need to get both versions, format them then use the built in compare tool. I was hoping there's a faster method: something along the lines of "auto-format and compare"...

Answer (score 0):

TFS will only do line for line comparison, so single string to single string. You are going to have to use an external tool if you want more information about what was changed.

I would suggest prettifying/formatting the XML and then doing the comparison on both versions, it should be fairly simple to spot then.

Answer (score 0):

I will be upfront I represent the company at hand, but I'm fairly certain this can help you.

This use case is exactly what DeltaXML is for so please feel free to take a look at our free evaluation or free online sandbox to provide you with a line by line comparison or your XML.

http://www.deltaxml.com/products/core/